# How to structure a Python script into multiple files?

Tags: python, file-structure

I've got a large Python script and would like it to be split into multiple small files. The best structure I found to date is as follows:

```
/myapp
   __main__.py
   __init__.py
   core.py
   my_mod.py
```

This has the advantage, that it can be called as follows:

```
python myapp
- or -
python myapp/__main__.py
```

and in `core.py` I can use:

```
from . import my_mod
```

However, the disadvantage is `__main__.py` which uses a hack so it can import its folder as a package:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3

import os
import sys

# add path to directory above so the imports work
sys.path.insert(0, os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(__file__)))

import myapp.core as core

def main():
    app = core.App()
    app.run()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Is there a best-practice solution for this? I don't want to install the script using pip, just copying the folder should be enough.

Comment: why the hack instead of `from . import core` as you do it in `core.py` for `my_mod`? Or am I missing something?

Comment: @Ev.Kounis I get either *attempted relative import with no known parent package* or *cannot import name 'core'*, depending on how I run the script. The problem seems to be that when using `__main__.py` Python does not register the directory as a package. This mechanism seems to have been built only for cases where the entrypoint script lies outside the directory.

Comment: What is the reason why you use `from . import my_mod`in `core.py` instead of just `import my_mod`?